how to solve netflix eureka client error in spring boot 3.3.0 and java 17
`Estoy tratando de registrar mi servicio en Eureka Client  para Spring boot version - 3.3.0-SNAPSHOT spring-cloud.version - 2023.0.0 java - 17 pero me dice que no encuentra las dependencias
he tratado de aplicar estas dependencias en mi pom
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>

he intentado con estas anotaciones
EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableEurekaClient
sin embargo me genera este
error Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:pom:unknown in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
no ha logrado registrar mis servicios en mi servidor eureka por favor ayuda `

specify a version or use spring cloud dependencies
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2023.0.2</version>
</dependency>

